# What model of bulb should I buy for BMW 320i 2006?

Tags: bmw, bulbs

I recently acquired a car from my dad a couple of months ago. This week, I noticed that one of the headlight bulbs is flickering and the bulb sensor shows up.

I'm not entirely sure what type of bulb should I buy. I'm no expert in terms of a car.

I have a recent question about the car that we have. It's a BMW 320i 2006 with "M".

[What's the difference between BMW 320i SE and Non SE?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25670/whats-the-difference-between-bmw-320i-se-and-non-se)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm roughly guessing this is an H7 bulb for low beam.  I prefer Osram/Sylvania, but obviously there are others.

BMW are the mostest analist of the bunch (I used to work for BMW NA), so there are quite the variety of variations of bulbs that may be suitable.  North American vehicles are limited in wattage by law, but Euro spec bulbs may have much higher output.

Pull the bulb and check the numbers on the flange.  I'm betting H7.  However, a "flickering" bulb might more likely be a corroded or loose socket connection than an actual bulb failure.  But a marginal filament connection could cause the same condition.

Wiggle wiggle - if that helps it's probably not the bulb.

Comment: @Ben  I also forgot to mention that if you have *gasentladungslampe*  (high voltage gas discharge Xenon system... the Germans are certain they invented it) and bulb flickering, the ignitor electronics are shot, and/or the discharge tube as well.  This is **eyewatering** expensive to repair.  Hopefully we are talking about good ole 'Merican halogen lamps.